# PTIJ: Halachic issues with Superman and Jews from the Krypton planet

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In the following cases, how does [Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman), or any citizen from the planet Krypton follow the Halacha?

1. Assuming Superman is invited over Friday night and isn't Jewish, how would one stop him from seeing Non-mevushal wine, if he has x-ray vision (according to those that hold that even seeing is a problem by uncooked wine)?
2. If Superman converts, how does he ever make Kiddush if, with his x-ray vision, he can always see the Challos?
3. How does Superman practice Shmiras Enayim/Tzniut if he can see through everyone?
4. Would Superman ever say Kiddush Levana more than once in his life, if he could always see the whole moon?
5. Would Superman die immediately, since he can see anything, theoretically including Hashem, who no man can see and live?
6. Did Kryptonian Jews (Jews living on Superman's home planet) cover Challahs during Kiddush, or tuck their Tzitzis in when entering cemeteries, if everyone had X-Ray vision?
7. Would Kryptonian Jews needs their Kohanim to cover their hands during Duchaning?
8. Can Superman bentch from anywhere since he can see his table via x-ray vision?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Some of these questions pertain to Superman every day, and not necessarily with regards to Jews. Possibly for this reason, he is often described and portrayed as a highly moral "boyscout".

Comment: Another point is the questions about Jews on Krypton. Because Krypton has a red sun, Kryptonian powers don't work there.

Comment: superman is actually invented by jews, and some say that they subconsciously based him off of the supernatural powers that Jews have when they do the will of Hashem, like how when Moshe was about to be executed by the egytianns, his neck turned to marble stone etc., and whem moshiach comes we will all fly to jerushalayim etc. [and moshe jumped all the way to the top of mount nevo in only one leap]

Comment: Mitzvos aren't applicable on Krypton because of "lo bashamayim hi"

Answer (score 2):

I think you are giving too much power to x-ray vision. I and presumably you have red color vision. If a photon of the red wavelength hits our eyes, then we will recognise that as red. If red light hits stained glass windows, we don't just see black since a windows is in the way, rather we see a lot of red coming through the clear glass, some red coming through the red glass, and a bit of light coming through the other colors.

So, what happens when you put a bottle of non-mevushal wine between Superman's eyes and the x-ray source? The x-ray goes through as if it wasn't there and he doesn't see it. Similarly for Challa, Hashem, Tzitzis, and the exact opposite for the moon. The earth can block x-rays and would therefore hide part of the moon's light.

Regarding Tzniut, there are several sources that require covering up to the collarbone. That can be problematic when it comes to x-ray vision. However, the solution is "simple". Rather than normal people being required to cover themselves with something that block the visual spectrum (ie. normal, non-see-though, clothing), Kryptons will have to wear lead clothing. Similarly with Duchaning, the Talit will have to be made of lead.

As for the table, that would depend what the table and wall was made of. It it was simple wood, then x-ray vision wouldn't help. If the wall was made of stone, then x-ray vision wouldn't help either. However, if the table was made out of dense material, like stone, but the wall wasn't, then that would mean that he could see that table.